# Potential energy stored in lifting a body upwards

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

How much potential energy will be stored in the body if it is lifted upwards with acceleration greater than acceleration due to gravity?

Comment: The gravitational potential energy depends only on the distance to the Earth, it does not care if it is moving or accelerating, that would be kinetic energy, and the total energy of the body would be the sum of kinetic and potential.

Answer (score 1):

Gravitational potential energy is not a function of the acceleration of the object, only a function of how high that object is lifted. Close to the Earth, the gravitational potential energy is given by $U=mgh$ where $m$ is the mass of the object, $g$ is the gravitational acceleration of the Earth's gravitational field (note: this DOES NOT care about the actual acceleration of the object), and $h$ is the height above the Earth. The higher $h$ is the higher the gravitational potential energy is.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with both answers. Acceleration would be a factor if one wanted to know the total energy possessed by the mass (potential energy + kinetic energy) when it reached a height h above the earths surface